# I'm getting the error : runtime error: division by zero ; for my code Can someone plzz help me

Tags: arrays, runtime, pascals-triangle

```
        int j;
        for( j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {  v.push_back(val);
        val= val*(i-j)/j+1;
        }   
   return v;
```

In the line val=val*(i-j)/j+1 ; the error is occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code to this-

```cpp
int j;
    for( j=0;j<=i;j++){  
        v.push_back(val);
        val= val*(i-j)/(j+1);
    }   
return v;
```

This error was occurring because you were dividing the value with `j` in line 4 that was initially `0`, however you were adding one but you should have used `()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what language this is in, but I would expect the division operator (`/`) to take precedence over the addition operator (`+`), so in the first iteration of the loop you will indeed be performing a division by 0 which is what the error is telling you.